# Power Apps - Checked toggles reset after Submitform

Tags: ms-office, submit, toggle, powerapps

I am new to `Powerapps`. I have a number of `toggles` in an `EditForm` named EditForm1. When the toggles are checked they cause text input boxes to appear, these can then be used to enter new information.

I then have a `SubmitForm` button (`SubmitForm(EditForm1)`), which saves the new information to an `Excel` table via `Dropbox`. Everything works fine except when I press the `SubmitForm` button the toggles return to their default mode, which is off. How can I keep the toggles on after submitting? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the answer to this question from the `PowerApps` forum (https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/PowerApps-Forum/Submitform-resets-toggles/m-p/62742#M25890).

Basically, using `toggles` inside a `form` was the problem, since submitting forms causes the controls to reset. So the solution was to remove the form and include my toggles on a blank `canvas`. Then, instead of using `Submitform()`, I use the `Patch()` function like so

`Patch(
    DataSourceName,
    Record,
    {
        DatasourceColumnname1: datasourcecolumnname1.Text,
        DatasourceColumnname2: datasourcecolumnname2.Text,
        ...
    })`

Where `DatasourceColumnname1` is the name of the column in the data source, and  `datasourcecolumnname1.Text` is the information I would like added to the data source (in this case, text inside a `text input` box).

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways PowerApps controls can be reset to their default value:

1. through the control's own Reset property
2. by calling the Reset(MyControl) function

So I would first check the Reset property of the toggles and set it to nothing or 'false', and then check the form's OnSuccess and similar properties to see if the Reset function is called from there.

Finally, if all this fails, I would abandon the oob forms and build your own so that you have full control over behaviour, see [this post](https://baizini-it.com/blog/index.php/2017/09/28/powerapps-101-create-your-own-forms/) for an example.

Comment: Thank you, that is a great tutorial! I don't suppose you are familiar with using the `patch` function to save changes?

Comment: Quite familiar, and there is an example Patch code in the tutorial

Comment: Yes I saw that. I'm wondering if that is a better way to save changes to the database?

Comment: If you mean more flexible and more controllable than submitting forms, then yes I think it is.  The Patch function returns the updated record(s) so that you can do error-checking etc.  You can also patch multiple records with one call.